# Why do objects of a given color appear white under light of that color?

Tags: visible-light, vision, perception

Under light from the sun, a red object will scatter the red component of light, and absorb all others. Hence, the human eye perceives it as "red". White objects scatter all wavelengths of light.

Yesterday I bought an orange light bulb. Under its light, orange/reddish carrots look white. Why is that? A "white" object would have to scatter all wavelengths of light, but there's only red light to begin with.

Here's a photo of a person's hand, in white then in red light. Notice the color of the red nails. Do they appear white in red light, or does the white skin appear red?

[image: Gorgeous red nails under red and white light]

Comment: Under red light, a normally "red" object will appear RED...

Comment: Or put another way, in the presence of monochromatic red light, then all objects (likely to be encountered in everyday life, notably neglecting blackbody radiation) can only appear red, or some less intense red approaching black. It would be good to add a citation or context to your question stating where you got the notion that red objects in red light appear white.

Comment: @PhilFrost: there's no citation, I just bought a colored light bulb and noticed the effect.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Some images might help. Until then I'm not voting to reopen.

Comment: @Ali: what if this effect is caused by an optical illusion? I did take a bunch of smartphone photos but they don't show the effect clearly. I'd probably need a professional camera. My friend also noticed the effect, so it's not some oddity in my visual perception.

Comment: @Ali - I've added an image.

Comment: _Do they appear white in red light, or does the white skin appear red?_ I see her nails red. Unless, you have a vision/monitor problem, I don't know why you ask this question.

Comment: @jinawee: turns out it's an optical illusion, something I've realized during the learning process as I posted the question. Thank you for encouraging me to post more questions on SE!

Comment: In that case you could add that it's an effect not captured by the camera. You can always post the same question in the Biology site, since they are still growing.

Comment: @jinawee: my comment was sarcastic (as I'm sure your hint at my vision problem was tongue-in-cheek). What you fail to realize is that a question author, by definition, doesn't exactly understand what underlying phenomenon is at the root cause of an observation, hence they may not be able to classify it as physics, biology, quantum optics, or whatnot.

Comment: @LucaMingarelli depends what you mean by "appear".  Spectrographic analysis of whatever light (if any) is reflected off a saturated red surface will reveal the light to be red no matter what the spectrum of the illumination.  But, our brains are not interested in the spectrum of the reflected light.  Our brains want to know whether we're looking at a ripe tomato or an unripe one, and our brains want to know that regardless of whether it is illuminated by a blue mid-day sky, or by the last rays of a red setting sun.

Answer (score 3):

Under a red light, red objects and white objects look the same (bright), while blue objects still look different from white objects. Your brain does all of the decision-making that goes into "that tomato looks the same as that baseball, and that baseball is white, so the tomato must be white."

Comment: Let's say I look at the tomato alone, through a peephole. There's nothing else white in sight. Won't the tomato still look white?

Comment: It's not an effect I've noticed. I have noticed that after reading for a while outdoors under a red light, coming indoors to a white light, everything has a distinctly greenish cast to it for a little while. So there may be some color-sensor exhaustion. That's more of a biology question, though.

Comment: I think the brain does some "automatic white balance adjustment" - picking the "whitest" object and referencing other colors from that. That, I believe, is how cameras do it. When the incident light is essentially monochromatic, this breaks down.

Comment: @rob You get a greenish hue? I get blueish. But yeah, as Floris said, that's because our brains are trying to correct for the colours and make whites appear white again

Comment: @Jim If it were blueish https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterimage would be a reasonable explanation, but since he said green, I was skeptical that the complementary color explanation could be the cause.

Comment: @jinawee Actually the anti-red in [this anti-flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:US_flag%28inverted%29.svg) is a pretty good approximation to the color I'm thinking of. It's kind of a teal, aqua, grue sort of color. Primary colors are surprisingly complicated.

Comment: @rob it might also be that our eyes are slightly different in their perception of colours